# value not displaying the right result

Tags: java

When I use numbers such as the one store in decimal the output just starts showing weird answers

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long decimal =444444;    
    long count = 0;    
    long a = 0;    
    long b = 0;

    while(decimal != 0)
    {
        a = decimal%2;                
        b += a* Math.pow(10, count);                
        count++;    
        decimal = decimal/2;             
    }    
    System.out.print(b);
}
```

this is the output that it prints 1101100100000011136 when the right output should be 1101100100000011100 for decimal 444444
now when I input 123456 it prints 11110001001000000 which is right

I must use long for this and without using strings so that is the code that I'm using but I can't find a way to fix it since mathematically it seems to work.

edit: the goal of the code is to display the binary representation of the decimal in called "decimal" without using string or arrays

Comment: What's the goal of the code? Some examples will be nice.

Comment: the goal of the code is to display the binary representation of the decimal

Comment: What about `Integer.toBinaryString( 444444 )` ?

Answer (score 0):

It because the maximum number a long can hold is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`(I get this from `Long.MAX_VALUE`)  and your `b` after loop for a while it exceeds that maximum value and cannot hold correct value anymore. there for you will have some unexpected result. So with `long` type, I'm afraid that your function only corrects with a small value.

**UPDATE**

Since you don't use `array` or `String` to hold the binary result, you can use `BigInteger` to store the value of binary, it can hold more than `long`.

Comment: is there a way to modify my while loop since i must use long i cant use integer

Comment: Your loop is ok, nothing wrong with your loop. It just the capability of `long` is not enough to hold your value. My best suggestion is using arrays/String/List/ multiple `long` (same with using an array) (which seem you can't).

Answer (score 0):

As what the other answers has pointed out, you can generate the output into a string instead as follows.

```
long decimal = 444444;

long a = 0;
String result = "";
while ( decimal != 0 )
{
    a = decimal % 2;
    result = Long.toString( a ) + result;
    decimal = decimal / 2;
}

System.out.print( result );
```